# bundle exec jekyll serve: cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler, github-pages

I am trying to contribute to a Github Page/Jekyll site and want to be able to visualise changes locally but when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` but I get this output:

```
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `require': cannot load such file -- rexml/parsers/baseparser (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:345:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:345:in `<class:Kramdown>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:60:in `<module:Parser>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:19:in `<module:Kramdown>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:3:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `block in require_all'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `require_all'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll.rb:194:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe/jekyll:8:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:494:in `exec'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.5/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I did `bundle update` and this the result:

```
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8 (was 1.1.7)
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using public_suffix 3.1.1
Using latex-decode 0.3.2
Using bundler 2.2.5
Using coffee-script-source 1.11.1
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using namae 1.0.2 (was 1.0.1)
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.7
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.4
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using gemoji 3.0.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using kramdown 1.17.0
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using rouge 3.13.0
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Using racc 1.5.2
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using jekyll-swiss 1.0.0
Using unicode-display_width 1.7.0
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using citeproc 1.0.10
Using csl 1.5.2
Using unf 0.1.4
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Using citeproc-ruby 1.1.13 (was 1.1.12)
Using activesupport 3.2.22.5
Using csl-styles 1.0.1.10
Using simpleidn 0.2.1 (was 0.1.1)
Using faraday 1.3.0 (was 1.0.1)
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Using jekyll-coffeescript 1.1.1
Using nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-darwin) (was 1.10.10)
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using bibtex-ruby 4.4.7
Using em-websocket 0.5.2
Using dnsruby 1.61.5 (was 1.61.4)
Using html-pipeline 2.14.0
Using ffi 1.14.2 (was 1.13.1)
Using sawyer 0.8.2
Using ethon 0.12.0
Fetching ruby-enum 0.9.0 (was 0.8.0)
Using typhoeus 1.4.0
Using octokit 4.20.0 (was 4.18.0)
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using github-pages-health-check 1.16.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using listen 3.4.1 (was 3.2.1)
Using jekyll-gist 1.5.0
Using sass 3.7.4
Using jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Using jekyll 3.8.5
Using jekyll-avatar 0.7.0
Using jekyll-github-metadata 2.13.0
Using jekyll-mentions 1.5.1
Using jekyll-optional-front-matter 0.3.2
Using jekyll-readme-index 0.3.0
Using jekyll-redirect-from 0.15.0
Using jekyll-relative-links 0.6.1
Using jekyll-remote-theme 0.4.1
Using jekyll-seo-tag 2.6.1
Using jekyll-sitemap 1.4.0
Using jekyll-titles-from-headings 0.5.3
Using jemoji 0.11.1
Using jekyll-scholar 5.16.0
Using jekyll-feed 0.13.0
Using jekyll-theme-cayman 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-dinky 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-hacker 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-leap-day 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-merlot 0.1.1
Using jekyll-default-layout 0.1.4
Using jekyll-theme-minimal 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-midnight 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-primer 0.5.4
Using jekyll-theme-slate 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-tactile 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-modernist 0.1.1
Using jekyll-theme-time-machine 0.1.1
Using minima 2.5.1
Using jekyll-theme-architect 0.1.1
Installing ruby-enum 0.9.0 (was 0.8.0)
Using commonmarker 0.17.13
Using jekyll-commonmark 1.3.1
Using jekyll-commonmark-ghpages 0.1.6
Using github-pages 204
Bundle updated!
```

Also, this is what the gemfile looks like:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'jekyll-scholar', group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
gem "github-pages", "~> 204", group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0" if Gem.win_platform?
```

Why doesn'it work?
I am fairly new to ruby and jekyll/github pages but I created another Github Page's website and this commands without a problem...

Comment: I had the same error with 'rexml/parsers/baseparser'.
I've upgraded my Gemfile to github-pages 212 (and jekyll to 3.9.0 and jekyll-feed to 0.15.1).

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I wasn't aware that running `bundle update` isn't directly updating all the gems used in the project to the latest version. Thanks again!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how I solved it thanks to @choas' comment:

1. Updated github-pages, jekyll and jekyll-feed gems by running `gem install github-pages`, `gem install jekyll` and `gem install jekyll-feed`. I had to do this step as a simple `bundle update` wasn't installing the latest version.
2. Modify those gems in the Gemfile to the latest version.
3. Run `bundle update`
4. Finally run `bundle exec jekyll serve`

I am not sure that all those steps aren't redundant as I am not very familiar with Ruby/Github Pages/Jekyll but it did work.

Comment: I indeed needed to remove the fixed version of Jekyll from the Gemfile, run update and then it worked for me.

Comment: I also had to upgrade to Ruby 3, which wasn't allowed because I was still running ont the Apple native version so this I also had to change. I'll add another answer to add these steps.

Answer (score 60):

I had the same problem, and I found a workaround here at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523

Add `gem "webrick"` to the Gemfile in your website. Then run `bundle install`

At this point, you can run `bundle exec jekyll serve`

For me, it works!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This worked for my first website but not on this one unfortunately.

Comment: Having the same issue as @tukanium where adding `webrick` doesn't fix the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72589554 helped me when this alone doesnt work (TL;DR remove the specific version from jekyll in gemfile as well)

Answer (score 18):

I also get this error. The solution is in the [documentation itself](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/).

> If you are using Ruby version **3.0.0 or higher**, step 5 may **fail**(`bundle exec jekyll serve`). You may fix it by adding `webrick` to your dependencies: `bundle add webrick`

Or add `gem "webrick"` into the `Gemfile`, then `bundle install`.

Comment: Important detail here is upgrading to Ruby 3. I had to add webrick for the error to go after updated the project to ruby 3.0.4

Answer (score 8):

I see that you're using `github-pages:204` and `jekyll:3.8.5`.

I made my project with the same dependencies work with:

1. `bundle update github-pages`
2. `bundle add webrick`

Comment: `bundle add webrick` got me past the initial error. Now says `cannot load such file -- 3.0/rubyeventmachine (LoadError)`. Unfortunately, `bundle add rubyeventmachine` didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install webrick and jekyll-mentions: open terminal and type `gem install webrick` then `gem install jekyll-mentions`.
2. Open your gem file and add gem "jekyll-mentions" and gem "webrick" in the pulgins:

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-mentions", "1.6.0"
  gem "webrick"
end
```

3. Navigate back to terminal, and execute `bundle install`.

You are good to go, I think. This process worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Simple remove the specific version of jekyll in gemfile, as that specificity causes dependency issues with the kramdown package.

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.2.1"
```

Remove the specific version of jekyll, like so:

```
gem "jekyll"
```

Add webrick gem to gemfile

```
gem "webrick"
```

Run bundler again.

```
bundler
```

Finally, serve

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you yours most closely got mine working. I apparently also needed a bunch of other plugins so my working Gemfile jekyll_plugins look like so:

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed"
  gem "jekyll-mentions"
  gem "webrick"
  gem "jekyll-redirect-from"
  gem "jekyll-sitemap"
  gem "jekyll-avatar"
  gem "jemoji"
end
```

then `bundle install; bundle exec jekyll serve`

Answer (score 0):

Having a gem installed, but seeing `bundle exec` complain about it missing seems to be quite a rare thing. While my problem is about a different application (passenger), this is the best thread I found about this topic. I post my solution here, so others can find it.

I had my application complain about a missing library, although it was definitely installed, when started with `bundle exec <app>`.

I found that the library needed to be mentioned in the `Gemfile` in the directory where I ran the bundle-command.

In my setup, I have two ruby-projects: A REST-interface (sinatra/passenger) and a custom library containing the business-logic. Both projects have their own Gemfile. The concerning library is used by the business-logic and so it was in that Gemfile. For some reason, starting passenger would crash with a complaint about the library missing.

The problem only went away, after I added that library into both projects' Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

@tukanium his own solution worked for me, except I also had to upgrade to Ruby 3, which wasn't allowed because I was still running ont the Apple native version so *this* I also had to change.

Here are the steps:

1. Install Ruby:  `brew install ruby`
2. Check version: `ls /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/`
3. Add to path (change version):
   `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
4. Check if succesful: `which ruby`
5. Reinitialize your terminal: `zsh`
6. Updated github-pages, jekyll and jekyll-feed gems by running `gem install github-pages`, `gem install jekyll` and `gem install jekyll-feed`. I had to do this step as a simple `bundle update` wasn't installing the latest version.
7. Add webrick: `bundle add webrick`
8. In the Gemfile remove all the version numbers (will auto to newest)
9. Run `bundle update`
10. Finally run `bundle exec jekyll serve`