# "bundle-exec-jekyll-serve" causes LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, jekyll

I am a novice programmer trying to use a Jekyll theme for my Github blog. This is my first time using it... and I'm having problems with `bundle exec jekyll serve` command.
(FYI, I'm using Windows OS.)

Here's the output:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `require': cannot load such file -- rexml/parsers/baseparser (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:345:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:345:in `<class:Kramdown>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:60:in `<module:Parser>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:19:in `<module:Kramdown>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `block in require_all'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `require_all'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll.rb:194:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/exe/jekyll:8:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/jekyll:25:in `<main>'
```

I tried these 4 different solutions:

1.

```
bundle add webrick
```

But had the same error

2. (referenced [bundle exec jekyll serve: cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65989040/bundle-exec-jekyll-serve-cannot-load-such-file))

```
gem install jekyll github-pages
gem install jekyll
gem install jekyll-feed
bundle update
```

But had the same error

3.

```
gem install webrick
gem install jekyll -mentions
```

Then added

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-mentions", "1.6.0"
  gem "webrick"
end
```

to my gemfile, then

```
bundle install
```

But had the same error

4. (referenced https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523)

```
bundle add sdbm
bundle add webrick
bundle add net-telnet
bundle add xmlrpc
```

But had the same error.

Is there any way I can fix this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand, Ruby moves all stdlib parts into gems, some are "default gems", as in, they are normally installed with Ruby and don't need a reference in your `Gemfile`, but some are "bundled gems" which also are installed with Ruby, but need a reference in `Gemfile`. The problem stems from a fact, that with every Ruby release, some "default gems" become "bundled gems".

Such a situation happened with `webrick` in the past.

In your case it's most likely that you need rexml, which just became a "bundled gem" in Ruby 3.0: https://stdgems.org/rexml/

All this about a theory, but a solution is pretty simple. You just need to do

```sh
bundle add rexml
```

and then `bundle install`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, and thanks to you, I could get pass the LoadError! However now I am facing an Argument Error that looks like this: "rb_delegate: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)"; Trying to fix this for days but I'm still stuck with the problem. I wonder if you have any ideas for this?

Comment: Not really. But I would recommend you to start a new question :)